# How to exclude a module while defining a library in version-catalog

Tags: java, gradle

How to exclude a module while defining a library using version-catalog plugin
In this scenario, I want to exclude org.yaml as defined below.
How should I do that?

```
> // faker testImplementation('com.github.javafaker:javafaker:1.0.2') {
> exclude module: 'org.yaml' }
```

My definition looks like this, should I exclude here or should I exclude where I call this library in build.gradle

> library('javafaker', 'com.github.javafaker',
> 'javafaker').version(faker)